# Why is $EX_{\tau \wedge n} = EX_1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm stuck on a passage in a textbook I am reading right now.

Let $\tau$ be an (almost surely) finite stopping time, $(X_n, \mathbb F_n)$ a martingale. Suppose that $X_{\tau \wedge n} \stackrel{L^1}{\longrightarrow} X_{\tau}$.
Then in particular we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} EX_{\tau \wedge n} = E X_\tau$. My book now claims that $EX_{\tau \wedge n} = EX_1$ and hence $EX_\tau = EX_1$.

But why is $EX_{\tau \wedge n} = EX_1$ true? (By the martingale property we have $E X_1 = E X_n$ but that doesn't seem to help me)

Comment: Look up the optional stopping theorem. (You actually might be proving one case of the optional stopping theorem from another, I'm not sure of the context. But the main idea is probably clearer if you look at the whole theorem at once.)